# Executar função após algum tempo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, tenho o seguinte código (apenas estudando):

```
$('#test').hover(function(){
        $('.box-one, .box-two, .box-three').hide();
        $(this).removeClass('test').addClass('another-test').stop().animate({'height':'210px'});
        $('.my-message').fadeIn();

}, function(){
        $('.box-one, .box-two, .box-three').fadeIn();
        $(this).removeClass('another-test').stop().animate({'height':'110px'}).addClass('test');
        $('.my-message').fadeOut();
});
```

Ao pairar o mouse em cima do elemento, devo esperar algo em torno de uns 0,400 segundos até que a função ative, porém se caso eu desista ou simplesmente passei o mouse por engano, a função deve reconhecer que o mouse não está mais em cima do elemento e com isso deve cancelar o que seria feito...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hmm interessante, aqui fica uma ideia que usa o `setTimeout` para despoletar a animação ao fim de 400ms do hover. No caso de o mouse sair, então o código limpa o `setTimeout` e o código dentro da função é ignorado.

```
var pairar;
$('#test').hover(function () {
    pairar = setTimeout(function (self) { 
      // usei a variavel "self" como parametro,                                   
      //  e que representa o "this" fora da funcao setInterval
        $('.box-one, .box-two, .box-three').hide();
        $(self).removeClass('test').addClass('another-test').stop().animate({ 
            'height': '210px'
        });
        $('.my-message').fadeIn();
    }, 400, this); // repara que passei o "this" como parametro aqui para o seletor funcionar. 
                   // Chamei-lhe "self" dentro da funcao mas podes usar outro nome
}, function () {
    clearTimeout(pairar);
    $('.box-one, .box-two, .box-three').fadeIn();
    $(this).removeClass('another-test').stop().animate({
        'height': '110px'
    }).addClass('test');
    $('.my-message').fadeOut();
});
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzTcg/)

Comment: A passagem do _próprio_ para "dentro" do _timer_ é de facto algo critico nestas implementações +1 Não me lembrei disso!

Comment: Acredito que essa resposta tenha dois problemas. Um seria o uso de `setInterval`, que define um timer que executa **várias vezes**, não apenas uma vez. Outro problema ocorre que a ação de saída sempre ocorrerá quando o cursor for retirado de cima do elemento `#test`, mesmo antes de 400 ms.

Answer (score 6):

Se tudo o que queres é esperar um X de tempo antes de efectivamente correr o código associado ao `hover`, um *timer* resolve a tua questão:

```
var tempo_espera;
$('#test').hover(
    function() {
        tempo_espera = setTimeout(function() { 
            // o teu código mouse hover aqui
        }, 400);
    },
    function() {
        clearTimeout(tempo_espera);
        // o teu código mouse out
    }
);
```

O que estamos a fazer é a criar um *envelope* sempre que o rato passa por cima do elemento, para que o teu código só seja executado após o tempo indicado.

Quando o rato sai do elemento, estamos a limpar o tempo de espera.

Comment: A tua resposta tem uma explicação melhor que a minha :p `+1`

Answer (score 5):

Eu recomendo o uso do plugin [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).

Entretanto, não é algo difícil de se implementar em Javascript puro, com o uso de `window.setTimeout(callback, millisecs)`.

```
var hoverIn = function () { ... }; // callback para o que fazer quando o
                                   // cursor entra no elemento #test

var hoverOut = function () { ... }; // callback para o que fazer quando o
                                    // cursor sai do elemento #test
var timeout; // referência do timer

$('#test').hover(function () {
    // ao entrar no elemento #test, o timer será ajustado

    timeout = setTimeout(function () { // quando o timer for disparado...
       timeout = false; // ... apagamos sua referência ...
       hoverIn(); // e executamos o callback de entrada
    }, 400);

}, function () {
    // ao sair do elemento #test ...

    if ( timeout )
       clearTimeout(timeout); // Se ainda houver referência ao timer,
                              // nós o desativamos
    else
       hoverOut(); // Caso contrário, nós executamos o callback de saída,
                   // pois hoverIn() já foi executado. 
});
```

Comment: O controlo quando o rato está a sair do elemento está excelente! +1 Pela verificação se deve ou não correr código associado :)

Comment: Boa explicação, `+1`

Comment: Ótima resposta. Eu ia escrever algo mas aqui já explica tudo.